# Updating nested-documents in mongodb(Java Driver)

Tags: java, mongodb

I am facing an issue while updating a sub document through MongoDB java driver.

The document structure is

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5c442474c1c50dbe19898e27"),
    "address" : {
            "apartmentName" : "apartment 1",
            "apartmentNo" : 1
    },
    "entityId" : "Id1",
    "entityName" : "Name1"
}
```

I am updating the document from a Pojo- 'pojoObject' as below:

```
ObjectMapper mapper=JsonFactory.create();
    String jsonString = mapper.toJson(pojoObject);
    Document doc=new Document("$set",Document.parse(jsonString));
    database.getCollection("CollectionName",pojoObject.getClass())
        .updateOne(Filters.eq("entityId",pojoObject.getEntityId()),doc);
```

Now if my pojo fields are as given below(other fields are null), it updates "entityName" properly.

```
Fields- {"entityName":"Name2","entityId":"Id1"}


{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5c442c0fc1c50dbe19898e59"),
    "address" : {
            "apartmentNo" : 1,
            "apartmentName" : "apartment 1"
    },
    "entityId" : "Id1",
    "entityName" : "Name2"}
```

However if I update only one term in the subdocument (other fields are null), the whole subdocument gets replaced.

```
   Fields- {"entityId":"Id1","address":{"apartmentNo":5}}


{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5c442c0fc1c50dbe19898e59"),
    "address" : {
            "apartmentNo" : 5
    },
    "entityId" : "Id1",
    "entityName" : "Name2"
}
```

ie. `apartmentName` field gets replaced too.

Is there a way I can update `apartmentNumber` without replacing other fields in the sub-document?

Thanks in advance :D

**UPDATE**

The pojoObject is created as below:

```
PojoObject pojoObject = new PojoObject();
    pojoObject.setEntityId("Id1");
    pojoObject.setEntityName(null);
    Address address=new Address();
    address.setApName(null);
    address.setApNo(12);
    pojoObject.setAddress(address);
```

Comment: share how you create 2nd pojo object. changes relate to list update

Comment: I've updated the question now :)